# Dovecot won't stop running

Tags: email, dovecot

I installed dovecot and postfix on my laptop a while back for hands-on experience.  I decided though, that one of my backup PCs would be a better testing grounds.  I removed postfix, but am unable to remove dovecot, or stop it from running.

When I try to kill the running processes associated with dovecot, they simply restart with new PIDs.  When I try to remove dovecot (which netstat shows me is behind these processes), I get a "is not installed" message from apt.

I don't know what's going on, hopefully someone can shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
ii  dovecot-core                                1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - core files
ii  dovecot-gssapi                              1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - GSSAPI support
ii  dovecot-imapd                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - IMAP daemon
ii  dovecot-ldap                                1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - LDAP support
ii  dovecot-lmtpd                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - LMTP server
ii  dovecot-managesieved                        1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - ManageSieve server
ii  dovecot-mysql                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - MySQL support
ii  dovecot-pgsql                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - PostgreSQL support
ii  dovecot-pop3d                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - POP3 daemon
ii  dovecot-sieve                               1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - Sieve filters support
ii  dovecot-solr                                1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - Solr support
ii  dovecot-sqlite                              1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2.1                                  amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - SQLite support
```

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo pkill -9 dovecot`? the package might be called argonaut-client or argonaut or something like that

Comment: Dovecot should shut down when the [`dovecot-core`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dovecot-core) package is removed.

Comment: How have you installed dovecot?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l 'dovecot*' | grep '^ii'`

Comment: Okay, very sorry to the above responders.  Tried to @ you all, but can't.  I thought I would receive emails as I was getting responses.  I didn't -- so just now seeing them.  pkill only restarted the processes (changing, of course, the PIDs).  I'll remove dovecot-core and I've also added the output requested.  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: @Nathan Osman it worked.  I originally tried to stop it from running by removing dovecot from the rc*.d directories, but they weren't present.  How is it that they began to run then?

Comment: Without installing dovecot on my system, I think dovecot restarts automatically. That's a configuration thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop and disable the dovecot service run

```
sudo systemctl stop dovecot
sudo systemctl disable dovecot
```

There is no need to remove the scripts manually.

To remove dovecot

```
sudo apt-get purge dovecot-core
sudo apt-get autoremove dovecot-core
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the old mailserver when still trying the new one - so no uninstall - thx.

`doveadm stop` and `service stop postfix` both no luck - more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is already an accepted answer to this question, but that answer didn't fix the problem for me unfortunately. My output was:
    `stan@vps:~# systemctl stop dovecot` 
    `stan@vps:~# netstat -tulpn`

    `tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:993   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   7339/dovecot`


The fix I found was using the command `killall dovecot`. This killed the process and allowed me to reinstall and reconfigure the mail server.